# Suggestion Bar Gone in Mathematica 9

Tags: front-end

I have been using *Mathematica* (version 9) for some time without any problems. Suddenly today I noticed the suggestion bar is no longer visible, and it's a feature that I use a lot.

I checked the options, and "Show suggestion bar after last output" is checked. Also I tried to reinstall Mathematica, but the problem remains.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Please do not use the bugs tag; it's meant to be added only when a bug is confirmed.  Try the suggestions [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TroubleshootingTheWolframSystem.html) first.  If that doesn't work try this: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464  The second is a full reset.  If you don't mind losing your settings, you can just do that and save some time.

Comment: It looks like the bugs tag can be re-added: it just got [broken](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/376357) in M9 only.